# Using Shared Preference in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

i had a question regarding an Android App.

1.The first Activity consists of getting the user name and after that take to the next activity.

2. In the New Activity i have to display a list of items which are hard coded, and the user can click on a list and get a new activity which has the details of the item. Also can add it to his WishList or like a basket and also delete it from there.

3.Now this is the thing i'm confused, another requirement is that when user exits the app and types this name he should get back the items in his basket.

So, my approach is that for points 1 and 2 I need a SQLite database to hold items,display and add to basket.
But i'm not sure about how to achieve the 3rd point.
I've read about shared preference and i kinda understand it partially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend saving a list of items into shared preferences.

You want to save the wishlist to a sqlite table. As they add items to wishlist.

You will probably have to have 2 tables to do this efficiently.

1. Table WISHLIST(basket) (id, username);
2. Table ITEMS (id, wishlist#, item name, item description, item value, etc.);
   wishlist# is going to be a reference to id of the WISHLIST table.

That way when they log in you can say.
SELECT * FROM WISHLIST where username = ? INNER JOIN ITEMS ON ITEMS.wishlist# = WISHLIST.id UNION select id, name, item description, item value, etc;

This way when a user logs in you can just call a method that passes in the username being entered and you pull back their wishlist. Thus you save their wishlist and retrieve it when they log back in.

Comment: What about a new user enters my app

Comment: When a new user enters the app: according to your requirement. You only have to create a new record when they add items to their wishlist.  You could create a wishlist of every user that enters your app, but some users will never get to that point. That is more up to you. I would personally create a cart for every user, and just keep the cart empty.

Comment: Are you storing log in information somewhere? If you are then I would keep the cart empty until they actually start adding items to the cart themselves.

Comment: how to create a new cart for every user and keep it empty

Comment: You can create a record in the Table wishlist. for example when they log in. You can say Insert a record to WISHLIST table.                        public void createWishlist(String username){
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put(USERNAME, username);
  db.insert(WISHLIST,null, values);
  db.close();
 }                                                                                                            That will create a wishlist for a username. At this point you have not added items to their wishlist, thus it is empty

Answer (score 1):

I create a "simpler" version of SharedPreference if you like. Github -> [KeySaver](https://github.com/mkiisoft/KeySaver)

and you use it this way:

```
KeySaver.saveShare(this, "your-key", "your-value");
```

to save/storage data. Could be use it inside Activity or Fragment (any context) with String, int and boolean

and you can get the values like this:

```
KeySaver.getStringSavedShare(this, "your-key");
```

You need the "your_key" to get the specific key for that value.

Comment: but how do i get back the items in the basket of a particular user?

Comment: you can save anything transformed into String... even json arrays, any kind of value pair, etc. Then you get the value/s anywhere you like and parse it back again. Depends on you after that.

Comment: can you link me to a tutorial or a blog related to this please?

Comment: well... that's kinda broad. You could check hash maps, create json, sqlite, content provider. That would help you to get started (google it, there is dozen of examples).

Answer (score 0):

You wanna preserve the items in your basket right. One way create a new table in SQL. Other way create an json file that keeps your data, save it and read it. SharedPreferences also works this way.

Comment: i can store items in my basket and even delete it, but when user has some items in basket and exits the app and when launches the app he should find his items in the basket

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreference is a reasonable place to save the user name.

Though you need to remember that if the user cleans the app's cahce, you'll lose this data (along with the SQLite database).

So if you want to save the user name, you can use a simple class like this:

```
public class AppPreferences {

public static final String KEY_PREFS_USER_NAME = "user_name";

private static final String APP_SHARED_PREFS = AppPreferences.class
        .getSimpleName();

private SharedPreferences _sharedPrefs;
private Editor _prefsEditor;

public AppPreferences(Context context) {
    this._sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS,
            Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    this._prefsEditor = _sharedPrefs.edit();
}

   public String getStringKey(String key) {
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(key);
    }

    public void saveStringKey(String key, String value) {
        _prefsEditor.putString(key, value);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }
}
```

From your activity you can do that:

```
     AppPreferences prefs = new AppPreferences(this);

     //get the user name
     String user = prefs.getStringKey(AppPreferences.KEY_PREFS_USER_NAME );

     //to save 

     prefs.saveStringKey(AppPreferences.KEY_PREFS_USER_NAME ,"the user name");
```